# How to format excel workbook generated by dynamic reports

Tags: apache-poi, dynamic-reports

I want to format generated excel file(generated by using dynamic reports) using apache poi (vesrion 3.7). I am facing basically two problems in formatting the excel.

1. Numbers are considered as text and I am getting warning messages in excel (Number stored as text).
2. Left indentation is not coming in excel, although it is coming in PDF and HTML.

How can I achieve these two things using apache poi in excel report?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Shikha Singhal

Comment: What code are you using to write the numbers into the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1: Number stored as text warning:

Set the cell type as Numeric:

```
Cell cell = sheet.getRow(0).createCell(2);      
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
cell.setCellValue(12345);
```

Issue 2: Left indentation for Cell

```
XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I am using the same thing to format the cell type to numeric. But in case I have a negative number, which I am representing with red color in braces like (0.0004). In this case it is not formatting it. How to format this cell as numeric and represent the number same as it was (I mean in red color and in braces). Any help please..

Comment: You will need to alter Code 2 and set text color as well. See http://thinktibits.blogspot.in/2012/12/Java-POI-XLS-XLSX-Change-Cell-Font-Color-Example.html

Comment: @LittlePanda HI am not using Apache POI. Am generating report using Dynamic Reports and i too have the same issue in Excel,Number stored as text. Due to this am not able to do any operations, How can i fix it?